# Telephone Number validation in billing and shipping on frontend?

Tags: form-validation

I want the users to fill the Telephone field in a formatted way, for example, the format in my country is 03XX1234567. How can I set the field to only accept a number in this format else give an error?

Comment: Which file to add this validation to?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159039)

Answer (score 4):

Please check below for an example for custom validation (Accepting only numbers and minimum number count should equals or above 10)

Assign the below class to the telephone field "validate-phone"

Then add the below script in that page

```
Validation.add('validate-phone','Dashes or spaces are not accepted',function(the_field_value){
    if((the_field_value.length >= 10) && (!isNaN(the_field_value)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```